# regular expression to check multiple words occurrence in a single line

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have htmltext as

```
<p><strong>Where:</strong> Esplanade Concert Hall <strong>MRT:</strong> Esplanade <strong>When:</strong> Tomorrow, enter code here
```

and i have the set of words

**Esplanade , Concert , Hall , MRT:**

Could there be a regular expression that considers all the 4 words and fetches the matching solution where all the 4 are coming up together in a single match.

What I want to achieve is from the string **Esplanade Concert Hall MRT:**  i want to get the possible match from the html file containing the specific line with all the words.

I am coding in as3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex of the form

```
(Esplanade.*Concert.*Hall.*MRT)
```

That would retrieve the entire line that contains those words in that order. Your requirements are somewhat confusing though.

Comment: thanks. I am not so good with regular expressions. this solution worked out as per my needs :)